# Spring-boot + Apache camel + Embedded tomcat showing The receipt handle has expired on SQS delete. Working fine in external tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, amazon-sqs, embedded-tomcat-8

Using apache camel for accessing SQS. After message is consumed from SQS it must be deleted from the queue but it is showing 'The receipt handle has expired'. We are facing issue when we do load testing, with few requests it is working fine.

The issue looks like with embedded tomcat, external tomcat is working fine with same load.

We configured embedded tomcat to use same version as external - 8.5.23 and also all heap and gc parameters set the same.

Whether embedded tomcat is a lighter version of external tomcat?

```
SqsConsumer:213 - Error occurred during deleting message. This exception is ignored..
 Caused by: [com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException
ReceiptHandle is invalid. Reason: The receipt handle has expired. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID:
```

We configured embedded tomcat to use same version as external - 8.5.23 and all heap and gc parameters set the same.

Using apache camel for accessing SQS. After message is consumed from SQS it must be deleted from the queue. It is showing The receipt handle has expired

Answer (score 0):

You will need to retain all the custom message headers till the end of the processing. Camel SQS will use it to delete the message from the queue.